# What's the difference between !ofstream.fail() and bool(ofstream)?

Tags: c++, file, io

I'm currently learning how to write to a file. Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream out;
    out.open("nbb.txt");
    if (!out.fail()) {
        // write something
    } else {
        cout << "Failed to open file!" << endl;
    }
}
```

So when I called the `open()` method, **if the file cannot open**, then the condition `out.fail()` would be true. However, I've tried to just use the `out` instance as a boolean. It works as well!

```cpp
if (out) {
    // write to the file...
}
```

So what's the difference between using `if (!out.fail())` and `if (out)`?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: They are the same. `operator bool()` is required to be defined as `return !fail();`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Answer (score -2):

```
.fail()
```

returns true if anything goes wrong, so using.

```
if(!out.fail())
```

is the same as `if(not(false))` which is `if(true)`

when you say `if(out)`automatically checks if values are anything other than 0, NULL and nullptr.

```
if(out)
```

when values exist this becomes `if(true)`

which makes `if(out) and if(!out.fail())` the same.

correct me if im wrong

Comment: You're wrong. 'if statement automatically checks if values exist' is false if not meaningless, and your use of `true` and `false` is at best misleading.

Comment: i dont think i am

Comment: correct conclusion but incorrect logic to get there. (0, NULL and nullptr are not involved)

Comment: please elaborate so i can learn